# Combining boost and ctypes

Tags: python, c++, boost, ctypes

I'm trying to pass a ctypes argument to a C++ module exposed by boost. I'm getting the following error:

```
File "ctype_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    test_mod.test_boost_func(i)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    test_mod.test_boost_func(c_double)
did not match C++ signature:
    test_boost_func(double i)
```

I understand that the type I am passing does not that in the C++ function. I don't know what I'm missing to make the double type in the Python code.

C++ code to generate the boost python module:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/args.hpp>


void test_boost_func(double i) {

    std::cout << i << std::endl;

}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test_mod)
{
    boost::python::def("test_boost_func", &test_boost_func, (boost::python::arg("i") ));
}
```

python code using ctypes to create and pass the argument:

```
import ctypes
import test_mod

if __name__ == "__main__":
    i = ctypes.c_double(100.0)
    test_mod.test_boost_func(i)
```

Comment: A ctypes type is not a Boost one, this cannot work for obvious reasons.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, this code is functional if I were to use this

test_mod.test_boost_func(100.0). 

I haven't defined that argument as a boost type. You are saying I can't pass a ctype as argument to a C++ function?

Comment: Yes. A ctypes type is not a standard type, and Boost doesn't know how to extract its content, hence the error.